# one-way symbolic link from repository to build directory

Tags: symlink

I am writing code inside of an svn repository but I *really* don't want to test run my code from within the repo. (I have a ../computations directory *outside* of the repo for this).  Ideally, the computations directory would be a one-way symbolic link from the repo so that each edit to the source (inside the repo) will be immediately available to the ../computations directory.

The problem is that there is no such thing as a one-way symbolic link.  An rsync shell script is about as close as I can get to a one-way mirror of the repo, but I am trying to minimize the chances of me forgetting to (or becoming tired of) 'updating' the ../computations directory.

What are my options here?

**More details:** I am working with C++ and Python code that spans more than one - but less than ten - directories, and editing in vim.

Comment: tell us more. What OS? What development environment? How are you building your code? What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here goes:

We have an rsync script named `snk` in `/usr/local/bin` that looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash
# this script will rsync -a the ../repo directory
# with the ../computations directory on various architectures.  
# leave this script here (in the repo!) and create a symlink to it from someplace in your $PATH

# get this host
HOST=${HOSTNAME}

# define various hosts in order to dictate specific rsync commands
hostA="someHost"
hostB="someOtherHost"


if [ "$HOST" = "$hostA" ] 
then
    rsync -zvai --exclude=.svn /full/path/to/repo/on/hostA/ /full/path/to/computations

elif [ "$HOST" = "$hostB" ] 
then
rsync -zvai --exclude=.svn /full/path/to/repo/on/hostB/ /full/path/to/computations
fi
```

Then we went to the Google and found: [this qeustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219892/vim-rsync-on-save) about 'vim: rsync on save' and gave it a shot.  Take a look at this portion of my new `.vimrc` file:

```
:if system('pwd') =~ "/full/path/to/base/of/repo"
:  au BufWritePost * !snk
:endif
```

This is a first-order approximation to a solution to my problem, I hope it helps!

*Thank you [vipraptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219892/vim-rsync-on-save/1219934#1219934)!*